# Group by query, each group has to not have any item not in a List

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, group-by, entity-framework-4

In need a query that will help me solve this.

Here's my table 'tags':

- id (int)
- name (String)
- user_id (int)
- hardware_id (int)

I am grouping the results of the 'tags' table by hardware_id. I also have a List of tags (`List<string>`).

I want to get the hardware Id of the groups that all of the tags in the custom List matches at a `name` in the table above.

In other words, I want to get the hardware_id's that the custom List tags matches their `name`'s. There might be `name`'s that doesn't have a match in the custom list, but all of the custom list tags, must be in  the group, and if it satisfies this need, I can the Id of that group.

I found it hard to explain and I didn't get an answer for that. I thought about doing it with foreach because it was so hard to solve, but I couldn't do it either and it's very inefficient to do it that way.

Example:

List : ['tag1', 'tag2']

Table Rows:

```
1, tag1, 5, 1
2, tag2, 5, 1
3, tag3, 5, 1
4, tag4, 5, 2
5, tag5, 6, 2
```

In this case, I should get the hardware_id of 1, because although one of the hardware Id's have tag3, it doesn't have any rows with a tag name that isn't in the List. IF the List had 'tag4', the hardware_id = 1 WOULDN'T be returned, because the List has a tag that the hardware_id group doesn't have.

If the Group doesn't have an item that the List has, it won't appear in the final result.

Someone game me this code, but it didn't work:

```
 List<decimal> matchingHardareIds = db.tags.GroupBy(x => x.hardware_id)
      .Where(x => x.All(s => tags.Contains(s.name.ToLower()) || 0 == tags.Count() && (s.user_id == userId)))
      .Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

In that query, when I have one tag in the List and in the table I have several items with hardware_id 1 and one of them has a 'name' that is equal to the value in the List it will return empty results. this is because the rows in the table for a specific group by hardware_id, has a row with a name that doesn't appear in the custom List.

I need a query in either Entity Framework or Linq. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var t = db.tags.GroupBy(x => x.hardware_Id)
          .Where(x => tags.All(y => 
                          x.Any(z=> z.name == y)))
          .Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: If this works I am going to give you all my stackoverflow points

Comment: For the example you provided, I did test it, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Can not provide you with the entity framework or linq query, but the sql solution is to count the matches like this:

```
SELECT hardware_id 
FROM tags
WHERE name IN (<list>)
GROUP BY hardware_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) = <listDistinctCount>
```

`<listDistinctCount>` is the count of distinct values in the list. Which you can prepare prior to the query.

Comment: There can't be duplicate names for the same hardware_id

Comment: Then you just don't need the DISTINCT part

Comment: You get read of those who don't match first. The once who are left, must have the same amount of rows as the List. How the hell I am going to translate it to Linq.. LOL... I need a moment.

Comment: Yep that is the solution. How to translate to Linq - can not help you :) As I see you need to make the group first and then use `where(grp.Count = tags.Count())`

Comment: You have it in the question, don't you? `s => tags.Contains(s.name.ToLower())`

Comment: Trying this one:   var ppp = db.tags.GroupBy(x => x.hardware_id)
              .Where(x => x.Any(s => tags.Contains(s.name.ToLower())))
              .Where(grp => grp.Count() == tags.Count());

Comment: I tried this, also endless errors: db.tags.SqlQuery("SELECT hardware_id FROM tags WHERE name IN ({0}) GROUP BY hardware HAVING COUNT(name) = {1}",
     string.Join(",", tags.Select(p => "@" + p)), tags.Count().ToString());

Comment: I will accept the answer, but will open a new one, asking people to help me convert it.